# Is there a recommended Power BI DAX pattern for calculating monthly Days Sales Outstanding (a.k.a. Debtor Days) using the Countback method?

Tags: powerbi, dax, finance, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

Is there a recommended **Power BI DAX** pattern for calculating monthly **Days Sales Outstanding** (a.k.a. **DSO** or **Debtor Days**) using the **Countback** method?

I have been searching for a while and although there are many asking about it, there is no working solution recommendation I can find. I think that is perhaps because nobody has set out the problem properly so I am going to try to explain as fully as possible.

DSO is a widely-used management accounting measure of the average number of days that it takes a business to collect payment for its credit sales. More background info on the metric here: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/dso.asp

There are various options for defining the calculation. I believe my requirement is known as the countback method. My data set is a fairly large star schema with a separate date dimension, but using the below simplified data set to generate a solution would totally point me in the right direction.

Input data set as follows:

| Month No | Month | Days in Month | Debt Balance | Gross Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 31 | 1000 | 700 |
| 2 | Feb | 28 | 1100 | 500 |
| 3 | Mar | 31 | 900 | 400 |
| 4 | Apr | 30 | 950 | 600 |
| 5 | May | 31 | 1000 | 400 |
| 6 | Jun | 30 | 1100 | 550 |
| 7 | Jul | 31 | 900 | 700 |
| 8 | Aug | 31 | 950 | 500 |
| 9 | Sep | 30 | 1000 | 400 |
| 10 | Oct | 31 | 1100 | 600 |
| 11 | Nov | 30 | 900 | 400 |
| 12 | Dec | 31 | 950 | 550 |

The aim is to create a measure for debtor days equal to the number of days of average daily income per month we need to count back to match the debt balance.

Starting with **Dec** as an example in 3 steps:

1. Debt Balance= 950, income = 550. Dec has 31 days. So we take all
   **31 days** of income and reduce the debt balance to 400 (i.e. 950 - 550) and go back to the previous month.
2. Remaining Dec Debt balance =
   400. Nov Income = 700. We don't need all of the daily income from Nov to match the rest of the Dec debt balance. 400/700 x 30 days in
   Nov = **17.14 days**
3. We have finished counting back days. 31 + 17.14 = **48.14 debtor days**

**Nov** has a higher balance so we need 1 more step:

1. Debt balance= 1500, income = 700. Nov has 30 days. So we take all **30 days** of income and reduce the debt balance to 800 (i.e. 1500 - 700) and go back to the previous month.
2. Remaining Nov Debt balance = 800. Oct Income = 600. Oct has 31 days. So we take all **31 days** of income from Oct and reduce the Nov debt balance to 200 (i.e. 1500 - 700 - 600)
3. Remaining Nov debt balance = 200. Sep Income = 400.  We don't need all of the daily income from Sep to match the rest of the Nov debt balance. 200/400 x 30 days in Sep = **15 days**
4. We have finished counting back days. 30 + 31 + 15  = **76 debtor days**

**Apr** has a lower balance so can be resolved in one step:

1. Debt Balance = 400, income = 600. Apr has 30 days. We don't need all of Apr Income as income exceeds debt in this month. 400/600  * 30 = **20 debtor days**

The required solution for Debtor days in the simplified data set is therefore shown in the right-most "Debtor Days" column as follows:

| Month | Month | Days | Debt Balance | Gross Income | Debtor Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | 31 | 1000 | 700 |  |
| 2 | Feb | 28 | 1100 | 500 | 54.57 |
| 3 | Mar | 31 | 900 | 400 | 59.00 |
| 4 | Apr | 30 | 400 | 600 | **20.00** |
| 5 | May | 31 | 600 | 400 | 41.00 |
| 6 | Jun | 30 | 800 | 550 | 49.38 |
| 7 | Jul | 31 | 900 | 700 | 41.91 |
| 8 | Aug | 31 | 950 | 500 | 50.93 |
| 9 | Sep | 30 | 1000 | 400 | 65.43 |
| 10 | Oct | 31 | 1100 | 600 | 67.20 |
| 11 | Nov | 30 | 1500 | 700 | **76.00** |
| 12 | Dec | 31 | 950 | 550 | **48.14** |

I hope the above explains the required calculation sufficiently. Of course it needs to be implemented as a measure rather than a calculated column as in the real world it needs to work with more complex scenarios with the user defining the filter context at runtime by filtering and slicing in Power BI.

If anyone can recommend a DAX calculation for Debtor Days, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This works on a small example, probably this may not work on a large model.

There is no easy way to do that, DAX isnt a programing language and we canot use loop / recursive statements etc. We have many limitations;

We can only mimic this behavior by bulk/ force calculate (which is resource consuming task). The most interesting part is variable _zz where we calculate for each row 3 version of the main table limited to 1/2/3 rows (as you see we hardcode some value - i consider that we can find result in max 3 iteration). You can investigate this if you want by adding NewTable from this code:

```
filter(GENERATE(SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATE(Sheet1, GENERATESERIES(1,3,1)),"MYK", [MonthYearKey], "MonthToCheck", [Value], "Debt", [Debt Balance]), 
var _tmp = TOPN([MonthToCheck],FILTER(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[MonthYearKey] <= [MYK] ), Sheet1[MonthYearKey], DESC)
return  row("IncomAgg", SUMX(_tmp, Sheet1[Gross Income]) )
), [IncomAgg] >= [Debt])
```

Next, I try to find in our Table Variable 2 information, how many months back we must go.

Full code (I use MonthYearKey for time navigating purpose):

```
Mes = 
var __currRowDebt = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Debt Balance])
var _zz = TOPN(1,
filter(GENERATE(SELECTCOLUMNS(GENERATE(Sheet1, GENERATESERIES(1,3,1)),"MYK", [MonthYearKey], "MonthToCheck", [Value], "Debt", [Debt Balance]), 
var _tmp = TOPN([MonthToCheck],FILTER(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[MonthYearKey] <= [MYK] ), Sheet1[MonthYearKey], DESC)
return  row("IncomAgg", SUMX(_tmp, Sheet1[Gross Income]) )
), [IncomAgg] >= [Debt]), [MonthToCheck], ASC)
var __monthinscoop = sumx(_zz,[MonthToCheck]) - 2
var __backwardrunningIncom = sumx(_zz,[IncomAgg])
var _calc = CALCULATE( sum(Sheet1[Days]), filter(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[MonthYearKey] <= SELECTEDVALUE( Sheet1[MonthYearKey]) && Sheet1[MonthYearKey] >= SELECTEDVALUE( Sheet1[MonthYearKey]) - __monthinscoop ))
var __twik = SWITCH( TRUE()
, __monthinscoop < 0 , -1
, __monthinscoop = 0 , 1
, __monthinscoop = 1 , 3
,0)

var __GetRowValue = CALCULATE( SUM(Sheet1[Gross Income]), FILTER(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[MonthYearKey] = (SELECTEDVALUE( Sheet1[MonthYearKey]) + __monthinscoop - __twik)))
var __GetRowDays = CALCULATE( SUM(Sheet1[Days]), FILTER(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[MonthYearKey] = (SELECTEDVALUE( Sheet1[MonthYearKey]) + __monthinscoop - __twik)))
return

_calc+DIVIDE(__GetRowValue - (__backwardrunningIncom - __currRowDebt), __GetRowValue) * __GetRowDays
```

[image]